# Replace two-wire thermostat

Tags: electrical, heating, thermostat

I'm replacing an old mercury thermostat with a digital one.

The new unit has 7-8 connections (labeled w1,wh,r1,rh,y,c, etc.) and a bunch of instructions about how to connect similarly labeled existing wires.

But there are no instructions about how to connect an unlabelled two-wire thermostat. How do I connect the new thermostat?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a good guide on thermostat wiring:
http://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Thermostat_signals_and_wiring

Most likely, all you should need to do is connect one wire to either W for heating or Y for a cooling system, and the other to R (or Rh for heating or Rc for cooling).

Answer (score 0):

Is it a line voltage thermostat? Do you have baseboard heaters or fan-forced heaters in the room? If yes, then you'll need a line voltage thermostat.